# Wordpress Multisite... Warning: fopen(F:\htdocs/wp-content/plugins/1626892348): failed to open stream: Permission denied in~ Apache on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache

getting the error message in the wordpress dashboard

"Warning: fopen(F:\htdocs/wp-content/plugins/1626892348): failed to open stream: Permission denied in F:\htdocs\wp-includes\functions.php on line 6333"

this is a wordpress multisite installed on windows 10 using Apache.

been banging my head over this for the last 6 hours and nothing I google seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

The file referenced in your functions.php line 6334 must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access.